# How to add columns from another table using a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named `Action`, which I want to add new columns to it.

The columns that I want to add are the result of this query :

```
SELECT DATE_AFFECTATION  ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Clôturé' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCloturé,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'En cours' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalEncours,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Gelé' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalGelé,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Hors délai' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalHorsdélai,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Nouveau' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalNouveau,
       SUM(Sum(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Clôturé' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION) AS cumTotalCloturé,
       SUM(Sum(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'En cours' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION) AS cumTotalEncours,
       SUM(Sum(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Gelé' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION) AS cumTotalGelé,
       SUM(Sum(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Hors délai' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION) AS cumTotalHorsdélai,
       SUM(Sum(CASE WHEN STATUT_Ticket = 'Nouveau' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Over (ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION) AS cumTotalNouveau
FROM DIM_Ticket
GROUP BY DATE_AFFECTATION
ORDER BY DATE_AFFECTATION
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "add columns", do you have a select query on the `Actions` table and want to join it or have you added new columns to the table and want to do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM...`?

Comment: You will need to 1) alter the destination table and add the new columns, 2) join existing records against this query properly and 3) issue the update to store the values. 2) and 3) is the same statement.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add sample data and expected results?

Comment: It's possible but it seems quite a bad idea.

Comment: Do table have any column(s) other than those returned by above query?

Comment: Yes the action table  have already other columns and i want  to add columns returned by this select Query .

Comment: what i exactly want to do is to have 'total cloturé' and 'total en cours' and 'total gelé' ....... as columns in my action table

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If you want to add columns to an existing table, then the syntax is `alter table`.  For instance:

```
alter table add column TotalCloturé int;
```

The default values are `NULL` or you can provide a constant default (such as `0` in this case).

You don't add columns with a query.

Hence, your question is quite unclear.  Are you simply trying to assign values to existing columns?  Do you just want a result set with these column values in addition to the columns in the original table?  Do you need triggers (or some other mechanism) so the values remain synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

Your query return more than one column.
You can't add a column and fill it in a single Query.